Create one hot wildcard string in python
I want to create a one hot wildcard string in python for scripting purpose for verification, which will be like this:
wildcard=["xxx1","xx1x","x1xx","1xxx"]
So basically, j'th element of wildcard[i][j] should be 1 & rest should be x.
I tried this but got 'str' object does not support item assignment error:
wildcard=["","","",""]

for i in range(0,4):
    for j in range(0,4):
        if(i==j):
            wildcard[i][j]="1"
        else:
            wildcard[i][j]="x"

print(wildcard)

It was pretty straightforward in C, but can't seem to replicate in Python. Is there a way to do this?


it was pretty straightforward in C, but can't seem to replicate in Python.

Unlike in C, in python strings are immutable, so you can't modify strings as you tried: wildcard[i][j]="1"
What you can do is create a new string and update your wildcard list with the new string:
wildcard=["","","",""]

for i in range(0,4):
    for j in range(0,4):
        if(i==j):
            fill = "1"
        else:
            fill = "x"
        wildcard[i] = wildcard[i][:j] + fill + wildcard[i][j:]

print(wildcard)

result:
['1xxx', 'x1xx', 'xx1x', 'xxx1']


I know you're trying to modify individual characters in strings, but strings in Python are immutable. You can't change individual characters once the string is created. So you can try the following code:
n = 4
wildcard = [''.join(['1' if i == j else 'x' for j in range(n)]) for i in range(n)]
print(wildcard)

The result is:
['1xxx', 'x1xx', 'xx1x', 'xxx1']

You can change n to other integer as need.
